# creating .bat file for intel booster mode

Tags: batch-file, intel

I got this `.reg` file for my laptop [from here](http://www.geeks3d.com/dl/showd/10060).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

It gives the option to disable the intel booster mode and I would like to create a `.bat` file now so I can turn it on *(for gaming)* and turn it off …like browsing the web. Unfortunately I do not speak code so one of you might help me out here!

Or is it even possible to add a command for certain applications so it gets activated with the app? Questions I have no answers for.

Comment: I think you're talking about Turbo clock speed.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost).  If you're searching in English, everyone calls it Turbo, not "booster mode".

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file with this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7" /f /v "Attributes" /t REG_SZ /d 2
```

To restore the original entry just replace `/d 2` with the default value. If you just want to remove the entry, use this:

```
@ECH0 OFF
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7" /v "Attributes"
```

However, there might still be a problem: Some applications read the stored registry value on application start while others read them on windows start only. If the second is the case you will have to reboot your system to make the changed value work.

Assuming you don't have to reboot, this is how you can combine the reg change with the start of a certain application:

Let's say, you want to activate the boost mode to play a game. The game exe is located at `C:\Games Folder\Gamexyz\gamexyz.exe`:

```
@ECHO OFF
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7" /f /v "Attributes" /t REG_SZ /d 2
START /WAIT "C:\Games Folder\Gamexyz\gamexyz.exe"
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7" /v "Attributes"
```

`START /WAIT` might or might not work depending on the behavior of the game itself. If it doesn't you will have to modify the code to make it work for each case separately. There are many ways to achieve this. If nothing else works you can still make your batch file loop around checking whether the game is still running using the `tasklist` command and delete the changed reg value as soon as you close the game.

Comment: This is a CPU power management setting (for the kernel to apply), not something that applications read or manage themselves.  So presumably this will work fine without a reboot.

Comment: @PeterCordes The code will change the registry entry as desired (I think). Or won't it?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your possible problem about some applications only reading them when Windows starts may not apply, because the only "application" reading it is Windows itself.  I don't even use Windows, but this looks like a good answer to the question of how to script registry changes, but IDK if this registry change actually enables/disables Turbo on the fly.  (Easy to test, though, if you have a simple infinite-loop program to run).  But I'd guess that *changing* the value from 2 to something else, rather than deleting the key, would be more likely to be good here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using REG (Registry) commands, you can use the POWERCFG commands. For example:

```
powercfg.exe -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

Source: [Enable/disable CPU turbo boost from command line](https://www.sakya.it/wordpress/enable-disable-cpu-turbo-boost-from-command-line/)